# Rotated line is offset

Tags: javascript, rotation, drawing

I've been trying to rotate a line that originates at the center of a circle towards the cursor in Javascript.  I have it moving but it is offset from the actual direction.  Is there is a reason for this?  I'd rather not have to add to the direction until it syncs up.

This is how I get the direction:

```
var deltaY = pointerY - charY;
var deltaX = pointerX - charY;

charDirection = Math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX) * 180/ Math.PI;
```

And this is how I'm calculating the new point which I want to be 100 points away from the center.

```
var directionInRadians = charDirection * (Math.PI/180);
var newX = 100 * Math.cos(directionInRadians) - 100 * Math.sin(directionInRadians);
var newY = 100 * Math.cos(directionInRadians) + 100 * Math.sin(directionInRadians);
```

[JSFiddle post](http://jsfiddle.net/jaeg/ErQ8T/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you perform the newX/Y calculation the way you do.
The proper calculation is actually a lot simpler:

```
var newX = 100 * Math.cos(directionInRadians);
var newY = 100 * Math.sin(directionInRadians);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/ErQ8T/3/).

Comment: -facepalm- You are right!  Thank you!  I guess that's just the way I've always been shown.